# Play WAV file continuously

Tags: c#, asp.net, wav, naudio

I have an ASP.NET + C # application that is not playing a WAV audio file. 
My code causes no error, it starts playing but stops shortly after.

My code:

```
AudioFileReader wave = null
WaveOut outputSound = null

wave = new NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader("C:/appwin/Audio.WAV");

OffsetSampleProvider OffsetSampleProvider = new OffsetSampleProvider(wave);

outputSound = new WaveOut();
outputSound.Init(OffsetSampleProvider);
outputSound.Play();
```

Comment: This will attempt to play music on the web server, not the client...

Comment: @LeeTaylor and how can i do to play on the client? in time, I can hear the beginning of the audio, a few milliseconds I would say

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: If the html does not contain html that deals with audio then the client will not hear any audio. I suspect that your development machine is also your server, so that would be why you would hear it.

Comment: You would also need to compress your audio. WAV files would be too big.